# Jquery add drop shadow to layover

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropshadow

I am using this layover plugin to display content: http://jquery.com/demo/grey/ I know there must be a simple way to add a drop shadow border to the layover, similar to: http://fancybox.net/ but I can't figure out what the best method would be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the liquidCanvas plugin.  It makes it very easy to add drop-shadows (and other things like gradients and borders) to any element.

There is a full write-up and tutorial at http://www.caffeinedi.com/2009/11/02/using-jquery-and-liquidcanvas-to-add-drop-shadows-borders-rounded-corners-and-other-effects-to-your-website-even-in-ie6-and-ie7/